# Find the Fourier series of $f$ in terms of the Fourier coeficients of $g$ and prove that converges everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Suppouse that $f$ is of class $C^2$ (it's second derivative is a continous function)and $g$ is of class $C^1$. Also such that $g,g'\in PC(2\pi)$ and $f,f',f'''\in PC(2\pi)$  and satisfy the differential equation $$f''+\lambda f=g$$where $\lambda\neq n^2, n=1,2,3,...$.

Find the Fourier series of $f$ in terms of the Fourier coeficients of $g$ and prove that converges everywhere.

(if $f\in PC(2\pi)$ then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\int_c^{c+2\pi}f(x)dx \quad\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$)

I'm stuck with this prove. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: To get started, multiply by $e^{-ikx}$ on both sides, integrate over a period, the right hand side gives you $\hat{g}_k$. On the left side, integrate by parts and invoke periodicity and you will obtain $c_k \hat{f}_k$, so $\hat{f}_k=\frac{1}{c_k} \hat{g}_k$. You just need to figure out what $c_k$ is.

Comment: @Ian what would soy suggest to check for convergence?

Comment: Convergence will follow by a comparison argument, but you'll need an estimate for $\hat{g}_k$.

Comment: (To be specific it's enough to have $\hat{g}_k$ bounded, and actually you have some decay, although in this case you do not necessarily have enough decay for $\hat{g}_k$ to be summable.)